# How to sample from a multivariate normal given the $P^T LDL^T P$ decomposition of $\Sigma$?

Tags: normal-distribution, matrix-decomposition

How to sample from a multivariate normal given the $P^TLDL^TP$ decomposition of $\Sigma$, and $\mu$?

Here, $P$ is a permutation matrix, $L$ is lower-triangular, and $D$ is diagonal

Given the Cholesky decomposition $LL^T$ of $\Sigma$, and $\mu$, we can sample by doing:

$sample = \mu + L * z$

... where $z$ is a vector of univariate standard normals.

I imagine that there must be some way of tweaking this formula to work with the $P^TLDL^TP$ decomposition, but my maths isn't quite good enough to see how to do that?

Comment: Perhaps your notation is confusing you, so let's write the decomposition as $P'\Lambda D\Lambda'P = LL'$.  Now isn't it obvious that $L = P'\Lambda \sqrt{D}$ where the square root is applied to the diagonal elements of $D$?

Comment: I thought that too, until I tried it.  Unfortunately, it is not true that $L = P^T\Lambda \sqrt(D)$, because $L$ is lower-triangular, and $P^T\Lambda \sqrt(D)$ is not, because it's been permutated.

Comment: But it's not necessary for $L$ to be lower triangular for this method to work! *All* that is required is that $LL'=\Sigma$.

Comment: So you knew the answer all along :-).

Comment: Well, I guessed at two plausible answers, but I lacked a way of proving/disproving either of them.

Comment: @whuber, care to convert this to the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With credit to whuber, I'm just typing up the exchange in the comments so that this question is marked as having an answer.

We can write $$
P^\prime \Lambda D \Lambda^\prime P=LL^\prime
$$

and $
L=P^\prime\Lambda\sqrt{D}
$ where we understand $\sqrt{D}$ to be the square root of the diagonal of $D$. The only requirement for this to work is that $LL^\prime=\Sigma,$ so it's not important in this instance that $L=P^\prime\Lambda\sqrt{D}$ may be permuted.